# Switching Images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What I am trying to do is simply switch a DIV's background image every x time interval.

This is what I have at the moment:

```
// Object of Background images per make
var bs = {
    "time": 2000,
        "url": {
        "BMW": ["url('img/cars/bmw/1.jpg')", "url('img/cars/bmw/.jpg')", "url('img/cars/bmw/3.jpg')"],
            "Audi": ["url('img/cars/audi/1.jpg')", "url('img/cars/audi/2.jpg')", "url('img/cars/audi/3.jpg')"],
            "GMC": ["url('img/cars/gmc/1.jpg')", "url('img/cars/gmc/2.jpg')", "url('img/cars/gmc/3.jpg')"]
    }
    //ect...
};
var Slider = $("#Slider"); // DIV element
function Slide(car) {
    var sLength = bs.url[car].length; // array # of pictures available
    Slider.css({
        "background": bs.url[car][index], // ?? here how do you auto increment & restart cycle
        "background-position": "center",
            "background-attachment": "fixed",
            "background-size": "cover"
    });
    setInterval() // here call Slide & ++ index ?
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    Slide("BMW");
});
```

Comment: Send `index` with your function, increment in your function and call `setTimeout` with `car` and `index`.

Comment: And reset it once it reaches length.

Comment: Please add more details to your question. What have the car makes got to do with it? Also use something like http://jsbeautifier.org/ to tidy your code - currently the indentation is inconsistent and confusing.

Comment: @rjmunro Well.. as you can see the question format has been edited, secondly Did you read the question? What does car makes has to do with it? Nothing and the question is not about cars. More details about what ? What did I have lunch? seriously no comments...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The remainder operator is really useful for wrapping things like your `index` around:

```
index = (index + 1) % length
```

...where `length` is the length of what you're indexing into (this assumes 0-based indexing).

So your `Slide` function can do something along these lines:

```
function Slide(car) {
    var urls = bs.url[car];
    var index = 0;

    function run() {
        Slider.css({
            "background": urls[index],
            "background-position": "center",
            "background-attachment" : "fixed",
            "background-size" : "cover"
        });
        index = (index + 1) % urls.length;
    }    

    run();
    setInterval(run, bs.time);
}
```

Comment: Just a note - remember that you must save the `setInterval` value to be able to remove it when you are changing of Slide. If not, you will waste a lot of callbacks for nothing.

Comment: @fcortes: Memory isn't the problem, but yes, if one ever needs to stop the repeated timer, one will need the handle. :-)

Comment: @T.J Thanks for the reply. basically index = (index + 1) % urls.length; limits the increment to # pics in the array. What is the % purpose here ? meaning less or equal ? Can't we use <= ?

Comment: Yes, it's true. I modified my response.

Comment: Nevermind Got it :) http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp

Comment: @Awena: FWIW, [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) is much better reference than that.